# On classifying groups of order $p^5$

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, classification

Can someone suggest me some source where the author has classified all non-isomorphic groups of order $p^5$ ? I need complete classification (not upto isoclinism), and also in finitely presented form . I found that with increase in value of prime $p$, number of groups increases. So, can we completely classify all groups of order $p^5$ for any prime $p$, in finitely presented form or get their structure description ?

Comment: Eamonn O'Brien's papers, or Charles Leedham,'s Green's papers may include references to such results. Marshall Hall dealt with $2$-groups of order at most $64$, I think, so that includes $2^{5}$ obviously.

Comment: @Geoff Your comment is useful to me. Thanks!

Comment: Probably the classification is uniform for $p\ge 5$ (or at least large $p$). (Uniform doesn't mean the number is independent of $p$, but the description ought to be uniform.)

Comment: The number of such groups depends on $p \bmod 12$.  See the last paragraph and table at https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf.

Comment: @KConrad I have found the general formula by G.Bagnera is $$61+2p+2gcd(p-1,3)+gcd(p-1,4)$$. So, for $p=3$, there are 67 groups in number. In your article, it is written 66. Kindly see into it.

Comment: Fixed, and I changed a reference to include Dokchitser's site https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/.

Comment: See section 6.5 in [https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07462](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07462) (in german)

Comment: @spin Your suggestion is really helpful. Although I don't know how to translate it into English, still it contains all the stuff I needed in mathematical form.

Comment: @spin Is there any easy way except google translator to convert the language into English ?

Comment: Can we get isoclinism class $\phi_2$ for any $p^n$ ordered group ?

Answer (score 7):

Bender in 1927 wrote a paper [A determination of the groups of order $p^5$](https://doi.org/10.2307/1967981) in English giving a proof of the classification of groups of order $p^5$.  The list of groups is also available in the GAP [Small Groups Library](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/smallgrp.html) package.